# Codebuild failing in DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase

Tags: aws-codebuild

I have this error in one of my codebuilds in the download_source phase:

**Decrypted Variables Error: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://ssm.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 52.95.123.56:443: i/o timeout**

i have checked all my vpc settings including the sg and route table but couldn't pin point the issue.

thanks

Comment: Sometimes it just fails for no reason, wait a few minutes and try again.

Comment: this has been happening for couple of weeks now

Comment: any update on this @DalalAlghomlas ? how did you fix it

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that this was a pure network issue for our account. i was able to resolve that by detaching and re-attaching in aviatrix.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by following this AWS article:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-parameter-store

**Also add CodeBuild ENV variables in this format:**
[image]

**And SSM in this format:**
[image]